# Splitting ng-repeat every 3 items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I'm iterating over a JSON object containing an array of event objects, containing an array of competition objects.

I wish to show each `event` in a table, and then each `competition` in a `td`, but only three cells per row

I'm using ng-repeat to return a list of tables for each event, but I'm having trouble with splitting the competitions into a new `<tr>` every three `<td>`s

Aside from rebuilding my own massive object from the JSON, what is the best way to do what I'm describing in Angular?

---

**Current view:**

```
<table ng-repeat="listing in listings">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">{{listing.name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="competition in listing.competitions">
            {{competition.id}} - {{competition.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Event Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>competition id - competition name</td>
        <td>competition id - competition name</td>
        <td>competition id - competition name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>competition id - competition name</td>
        <td>competition id - competition name</td>
        <td>competition id - competition name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.loading = true;

  $http.get('scripts/JSON/events.json').then(function (response) {
    var listings = response['data'].events;

    $scope.listings = listings;
  });
});
```

**events.json**

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "id": 418,
        "name": "et ullamco",
        "competitions": [
            {
                "id": 933,
                "name": "qui in deserunt occaecat et",
                "startTime": 1381092189
            },
            {
                "id": 853,
                "name": "eu enim ex incididunt do",
                "startTime": 1380708266
            },
            {
                "id": 5738,
                "name": "ad est ut aliquip et",
                "startTime": 1381366623
            },
            {
                "id": 7599,
                "name": "sit ex voluptate aliqua dolor",
                "startTime": 1381284106
            },
            {
                "id": 7481,
                "name": "laborum consequat deserunt do aliqua",
                "startTime": 1380874273
            },
            {
                "id": 3441,
                "name": "amet reprehenderit sint sunt proident",
                "startTime": 1380554850
            },
            {
                "id": 1959,
                "name": "ullamco minim minim in voluptate",
                "startTime": 1380651981
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a table but the semantics of your data indicate you have a list of lists. You should consider outputting this with `<ul><li>` instead of a grid.

```
<ul ng-repeat="listing in listings">
    <li>
        <h2>{{listing.name}}</h2>
        <ul ng-repeat="competition in listing.competitions">
            <li>
              {{competition.id}} - {{competition.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can achieve your desired layout with CSS quite easily using the above HTML. Checkout the "block grids" in Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation for examples. Tables should generally be used only for data that is actually tabular.

**However...**

You're question does still bear answering since there may be other reasons to alternate templates in the way you suggest. You could use a function for this to get things three at a time:

```
<table ng-repeat="listing in listings">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">{{listing.name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="group in competitions">
        <td ng-repeat="competition in group">
            {{competition.id}} - {{competition.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In your controller you can create a "list of lists" to bind to the nested repeaters

```
// Adapted from Fresheyeball's solution

$scope.competitions = []
compSet = []
for(var i; i < $scope.listings.competitions; i++){
   var competition = $scope.listings.competitions[i];
   if( i % 3 ){
      $scope.competitions.push(compSet);
      compSet = [];
   }
   compSet.push(competition);
}
```

Comment: Normally, I would use a list, but unfortunately I'm being forced to use pre-existing markup. Legacy code and all that... :(

Comment: I've added an alternative solution for you. I do realize sometimes these things force themselves on you. There are probably many ways to skin this cat though, grouping your arrays is probably just one of the more direct.

Comment: Thanks! Although with this I'm now running into a `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` error (the end result is displaying as desired, though). Is this because it's running in the view after the data has been passed?

I'm starting to think it may be best to push hard on changing the markup

Comment: After each digest angular checks all properties (including functions) for changes again and if it finds changes it will run a digest again. My guess is it is seeing something different but it is insignificant. I'd consider @Fresheyeball's solution which is basically the same idea but instead of a "group3" function you just group your competitions by three when you load them. This may work better. I've updated the solution to reflect that.

Comment: The code that creates the lists of code sets seems buggy. Should probably be something like `if( i !=0 && !(i % 3))`